# android live streaming error Error (1,-2147483648)

Tags: android, rtsp

I want to play live streaming video in server(wowza) to android device?
I have used  [this code](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/simple-example-using-videoview-to-play.html) its working perfect in emulator but it won't work in android device its showing error like this `Error (1,-2147483648)` some one guide me how to play **rtsp** url video into android device. this is my code

```
public class AnVideoView extends Activity {

String SrcPath = "rtsp://myip/live/mpegts";

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
       myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
       myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
       myVideoView.requestFocus();
       myVideoView.start();
   }
}
```